# Convert vars from nested yaml structure to a list

Tags: ansible, yaml

I have a yaml config file that has `watcher` field in various tree branches and levels of `routes` variable. What I would like to get is a list containing all distinct `watcher` values from the whole `routes` tree. Has anyone come across any smart way to parse such a yaml tree? Thanks!

```
  routes:
  - match:
      watcher: w1
      job: monitoring
    receiver: w1_support
    group_by: ['alertname', 'severity', 'watcher']
    group_wait: 1m
    group_interval: 5m
    repeat_interval: 24h
    routes:
    - match:
        watcher: w1
      receiver: w1_support
      continue: true
    - match:
        watcher: w2
      receiver: w2_support
      continue: true
    - match:
        watcher: w3
      receiver: w3_support
      continue: true
```

Ultimately I would like to use the target formula instead of `watchers` below - sth like:

```
- key: GLOBAL_HDP_WATCHERS
    value: "{{ <<watchers>> | list | unique | join(',') }}"
```

Desired output: `w1,w2,w3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend the below approach in all situations. But since we have no idea how deep your structure can get and ansible not being that good in recursive browsing and tree walking, I would work directly on the textual data.

For the below example, I created a file on my controller (this the same content you have shared, just here for the sake of completeness.):

**ext.yml**

```yaml
 routes:
 - match:
     watcher: w1
     job: monitoring
   receiver: w1_support
   group_by: ['alertname', 'severity', 'watcher']
   group_wait: 1m
   group_interval: 5m
   repeat_interval: 24h
   routes:
   - match:
       watcher: w1
     receiver: w1_support
     continue: true
   - match:
       watcher: w2
     receiver: w2_support
     continue: true
   - match:
       watcher: w3
     receiver: w3_support
     continue: true
```

Then the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
      - vars:
          regex: >-
              ^\s*watcher:\s*(\S*)$
        debug:
          msg: "{{ lookup('file', 'ext.yml').split('\n') | select('match', regex) 
           | map('regex_replace', regex, '\\g<1>') | unique | sort | join(',') }}"
```

Gives:

```
PLAY [localhost] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "w1,w2,w3"
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```